# FragmentTransaction replace vs add. Recreation issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In the project I'm developing there's sequence of fragments that get swapped with `replace`: A -> B -> C.

One thing I don't like about it is that when the backstack is popped fragments get recreated and I lose UI settings and I also need to dance around data loading and the lifecycle. On the other hand if I were to use the `add` method it would not destroy the fragments but it also makes me worry about memory consumption - can it lead to `OutOfMemoryException`? Does the framework handle LRU hidden fragments?

Is there any way to combine benefits of `add` and `replace`? Maybe I should try to use `add` + `hide`?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add, hide, and show is what you want. Use add when you first create the fragments, hide the fragment you are replacing, and show a fragment that was previously showing. You don't want to use replace because that will tear down the view hierarchy of the old fragment, and you will lose the fragment's state.

Comment: Thanks. And what about memory consumption? Have you tried stacking memory-intense fragments and see whether the framework tries to collect LRU fragments that're hidden?

Comment: Android might well recover some memory if it needs it, but it would maintain the state if it did so. The main time I've had memory issues is with images -- trying to load large ones mainly.